# Trouble with C code - Setting up UART with e2studio

Tags: c

I'm currently doing a project, using RL78G14 as microcontroller. The project involves making an IR remote and control panel. If been trying to write code to setup a UART. I get an few warning messages of passing an incompatible pointer type when passing TxBuf and RxBuf, and my UART doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with the code?

```
void main(void)

{
    R_MAIN_UserInit();

uart1Status = R_UART1_Receive(&RxBuf[0],1); // Prime UART1 Rx

while (1U)
{
    //Check if byte received on UART
            if (RxFlag)
            {
                // clear rx flag
                RxFlag = 0U;

                //Echo back the received character
                TxBuf[0] = RxBuf[0];

                //Send TX buffer, and specify how many characters to write
                uart1Status = R_UART1_Send(TxBuf,1);

                // re-Prime UART Rx
                uart1Status = R_UART1_Receive(RxBuf,1);
            }


            //If a character has been transmitted
            if (TxFlag)
            {
                // End of UART2 transmit
                TxFlag = 0U;   // clear tx flag
            }
}

/***********************************************************************************************************************
* Function Name: R_UART1_Receive
* Description  : This function receives UART1 data.
* Arguments    : rx_buf -
*                    receive buffer pointer
*                rx_num -
*                    buffer size
* Return Value : status -
*                    MD_OK or MD_ARGERROR
***********************************************************************************************************************/
MD_STATUS R_UART1_Receive(uint8_t * const rx_buf, uint16_t rx_num)
{
    MD_STATUS status = MD_OK;
if (rx_num < 1U)
{
    status = MD_ARGERROR;
}
else
{
    g_uart1_rx_count = 0U;
    g_uart1_rx_length = rx_num;
    gp_uart1_rx_address = rx_buf;
}

return (status);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************
* Function Name: R_UART1_Send
* Description  : This function sends UART1 data.
* Arguments    : tx_buf -
*                    transfer buffer pointer
*                tx_num -
*                    buffer size
* Return Value : status -
*                    MD_OK or MD_ARGERROR
***********************************************************************************************************************/
MD_STATUS R_UART1_Send(uint8_t * const tx_buf, uint16_t tx_num)
{
    MD_STATUS status = MD_OK;

if (tx_num < 1U)
{
    status = MD_ARGERROR;
}
else
{
    gp_uart1_tx_address = tx_buf;
    g_uart1_tx_count = tx_num;
    STMK1 = 1U;    /* disable INTST1 interrupt */
    TXD1 = *gp_uart1_tx_address;
    gp_uart1_tx_address++;
    g_uart1_tx_count--;
    STMK1 = 0U;    /* enable INTST1 interrupt */
}

return (status);
}
```

Comment: Is your problem related to coding or UART peripheral debugging ?

Comment: My code. I sort of fixed the code.My UART is not connecting, but  realterm is showing I'm transmitting something. Must be my connections. Will check my wiring first, than ask again.

Comment: Then you might have swapped TX & RX lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are using development board, R11 Pin check. It is connected to CAN RXD chip TJA1050T, and hence not receiving any data. Cut R11 jumper and it will start working.
2. Did you Started UART1 ? need to start it in Initialization.